# How to compress a series of numbers into a single number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For example, if you have $28,21,11,36$; how can you turn these into a single number such that some one else who knows the way you compressed them can restore the series unambiguously and in the original order with just the output?

Attempted general formula:

$f(\{a, b, c, d, ...\})=X$

$f^{-1}(X) = \{a, b, c, d, ...\}$

Comment: Map it to $2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$ where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime.  That's always un-doable because of unique factorization.

Comment: @Gregory Grant
That is a good idea, it is simple and practical, there is only a slight irritation in that there are no simple formula to generate prime numbers, but if anyone would write that as a formal answer, I think it will be acceptable.

Comment: Well as long as your list isn't too big, the first million primes are well known at least.  And factoring is not too hard as long as the primes involved are not too extremely large.  But for very long lists this won't be so practical.

Comment: BTW I did post it as a formal answer.

Comment: Can the numbers be negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map it to $2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$ where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime.  That's always un-doable because of unique factorization.

Comment: What if the numbers can be negative?

Comment: @martycohen then you end up with a rational number, and the process can still be done. Alternatively, let $p_{2k}$ encode the magnitude of $n_k$ and let $p_{2k+1}$ encode it's sign (via positive being $0$ and negative being $1$)

Comment: @martycohen oh wow I feel dumb, I posted that comment before I saw your answer

Comment: That's fine with me. Duplicate answers are to be expected, and they are fine if independent. I upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 2):

To handle negative as well as positive integers:

If the numbers are
$(a_i)_{i=1}^n$,
and
$(p_j)_{j \ge 1}$
are the primes in
increasing order,
let
$N = \prod_{i=1}^n p_{2i-1}^{sign(a_i)}p_{2i}^{|a_i|+1}
$
where
$sign(n) = 0$ if $n \ge 0$
and
$sign(n) = 1$ if $n \lt 0$.